# Cannot get html webpage to center on iphone screen

Tags: html, css

I have made a webpage and I am trying to acccess from my iphone - the code is below.

How do I center the tables on my iphone browser (safari)? Also, I seem to be able to scroll to the right on my phone, how do I restrict the page layout size so this cant happen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(10);"><img src="temp" id="c1" width="300" height="330"></a> 
<br>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(11);"><img src="temp" id="c2" width="300" height="330"></a> 
<br>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(12);"><img src="temp" id="c3" width="300" height="330"></a> 
<br>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(13);"><img src="temp" id="c4" width="300" height="330"></a> 
<br>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(14);"><img src="temp" id="c5" width="300" height="330"></a> 
<br>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(15);"><img src="temp" id="c6" width="300" height="330"></a> 
<br>
<a href="javascript:gotoPage(16);"><img src="temp" id="c7" width="300" height="330"></a> 


 </tr>
</table>
<script>
var $scope;
function gotoPage(page) {
    $scope.send({payload: page});
};

(function(scope) {
    $scope = scope;
})(scope);
</script>
</html>
```

Tried code above, but can't get it to work.

Comment: You should at least use a viewport meta tag so the iphone knows how to size your website. It might even fix your problem. Google it.

Comment: invalid HTML Markup. A `<table>` nor a `<script>` tag can not be a direct child of the `html` tag. You miss the `head` and `body` elements and a closing `</td>` tag (along some other markup issues). Also note, that tables are for displaying tabular data not to align items!

Answer (score 0):

Minimum reproduceable code to make one of your image to center. Ideally, use `<tr>` instead of `<br>` for each item. And wrap your content in a `<td>`.

```
<table  width = "100%" height= "100%">
    <tr style="text-align:center">
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:gotoPage(10);"><img src="temp" id="c1" width="300" height="330"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As for Scroll, you need to use dynamic height/width instead of hardcoding values. You can use media queries/ CSS frameworks (bootstrap/tailwind) or some scripting language.

Answer (score -1):

you can use margin property in css to center the table horizontally and overflow property in css to hide the hirizontal scroll bar . I think adding the following styles into your html will help you.

```
<style>
    /* Center the table horizontally */
    table {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /* Restrict the page layout size */
    body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, however the page is too big for iphone screen. I can move it across and see blank areas.

How do I restrict it so the total page width is the width of the images (i.e. 300)